# Changing the format of returned records when using multiple groups in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given a Table/Model called Assignment with the fields:

```
id
student_id
grade (e.g. A, B, C)
... some other stuff
```

How can I get a list of the students and how many of each grade they have?

The nearest I've got has been:

```
Assignment.group(:student_id).group(:grade).count
```

But this gives me the data in the format:

```
{[student_id, grade] => count, [student_id, grade] => count, ...}
```

eg.

```
{
  [1, "A"] => 8, 
  [1, "B"] => 6, 
  [2, "A"] => 7, 
  [2, "F"] => 5
}
```

Is there a way I can get the array to be on the value side so I can easily loop over and print out the students results? i.e. like this:

```
{
  1 => {"A" => 8, "B" => 6}, 
  2 => {"A" => 7, "F" => 5}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nearest you've got is the final one. Now, you need to slightly reindex results:

```
student_grades_count = {
  [1, "A"] => 8, 
  [1, "B"] => 6, 
  [2, "A"] => 7, 
  [2, "F"] => 5
}

student_grades_count = student_grades_count.reduce({}) do |sum, ((student_id, grade), count)|
  sum[student_id] ||= {}
  sum[student_id][grade] = count
  sum
end
```

Comment: I had feared that was the case - I was hoping I could avoid Rails doing it one way then me having to re-do it in a different structure! Thanks though!